# How do I access an attribute's value in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to bind a model to an attribute in a directive.

Javascript --

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.text = "abc"
};

angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive("load", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(attrs);
           element.html(someFunction(attrs.text));
        }
    };
});
```

HTML --

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
    <load text="Hello {{text}}"></load>
</div>
```

You can find the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaGy6/). In the fiddle I have done away with `someFunction`.

Comment: What's your question and what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want the scope within the directive, it's there already within the link function as 'scope.text'.

Comment: demo won't work because you haven't included angular library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick plunk showing 5 different ways to get to scope from within a directive.  The last one is the one you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/e2mMAq

Comment: and if I want to do the same sort of resolution with the `element.text()` value, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "resolution". Are you wanting the value of the text in the element?

Comment: `<div templated></div>` is sufficient -- no need for attribute value of `"{{text}}"`.

Comment: Just FYI, your last example could also use `scope.$watch` instead of `attrs.$observe` (+1 BTW).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I believe you are trying to do, you need to make two modifications:

1. You have replace set to true, so you should probably add a template to your code to replace the element with your new markup.
2. At the time that the linking phase occurs, the interpolation has not been evaluated yet, so you need to observe the attribute in order to look for changes.

   ```
     angular.module('myApp', [])
         .directive('load', function($compile) {
             return {
                 restrict: 'E',
                 replace: true,
                 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                     console.log(attrs);
                     element.html(attrs.text);

                     attrs.$observe('text', function(value) {
                         console.log('new value = ' + value);
                         element.html(value);
                     });
                 }

             };
         });
   ```

Take a look at the section [observing interpolated attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more details.